# Flutter Dynamically change text size while still looking good

Tags: flutter

I am trying to change text size within a container in Flutter. Every solution I've found expands the text to the edges of the box within looking good on different devices. What is the best way to make text suitable of different device sizes?

Comment: My advise is to not change the text size directly relative to screen size. In most cases, Scalling text relative to screen size wont help. Instead it becomes harder for the users to use. Just have lower limit and upper limit not exceeding 4 pts in difference and based on the available space, scale between that lower and upper limit.

Answer (score 1):

Using `BoxFit.scaleDown` and fixing the FontSize you can adjust the maximum size of the font.

Normal purpose use below code

```
Flexible(
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    child: AutoSizeText(
      'your specific text',
      maxLines: 1,
      style: TextStyle(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

If the content is small, it occupies the minimum width with the specified font size. At the same time, if the content is large, it resizes to the smallest font size.

```
FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                      child: 
                          Text(
                            "Text here",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          ),)
```

If you need the text to fill the entire width, using any font size use `BoxFit.cover`

```
FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      child: 
                          Text(
                            "Text here",
                            //style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          ),)
```

you can use this package in addition
[auto_size_text: ^3.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)